# Dart - Error to page load after pub serve

Tags: dart, dart-pub

I have a dart project with this transforms

```
transformers:
- angular2:
    platform_pipes:
      - 'package:angular2/common.dart#COMMON_PIPES'
    entry_points: web/main.dart
    resolved_identifiers:
        BrowserClient: 'package:http/browser_client.dart'
        Client: 'package:http/http.dart'    
- dartson
- dart_to_js_script_rewriter
```

First I did `pub serve` by default to port 8080,

It looks finish successfully

> pub serve
>
> Loading source assets...
>
> Loading angular2 and dartson transformers...
>
> Serving XXX web on http://localhost:8080
>
> Build completed successfully

Then, I tried to load the page http://localhost:8080
but I get this error:

> **404 Not Found**
>
> Could not find asset web in package XXX.

Anyone help?

Comment: Can you please provide more information about your project? `transformers` section in `pubspec.yaml` directory structure (which file is where)

Comment: I edit the question

Comment: Your project has a `web` directory with an `index.html` in it? How did you create the project? Did you use stagehand?

Comment: Yes, I have a web directory with index.cshtml in it (maybe it's not support cshtml?). I didn't create the project, so I don't know about this. what do you mean "stagehand"?

Comment: Ok, I answer my self... there is a problem with `index.cshtml` of MVC... 
do you know if there is a resolution for this?

Comment: Nope, no idea. . . .